# Mui text field error exclamation mark not coming properly when error helper text is large

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI version 5.4 and I have a sign-in form and applied validations on it. Validation is appearing properly but my problem is when I placed a long texted error message the exclamation mark is coming below outlined text field of the MUI material.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
<Box
            component="form"
            role="form"
            sx={{
              "& .MuiFormHelperText-root": { color: "#d32f2f" },
              "& .MuiInputLabel-formControl": { paddingTop: "5px" },
            }}
          >
            <Box mb={2}>
              <TextField
                type="email"
                label="Email"
                variant="standard"
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => emailHandler(e)}
                error={emailError}
                helperText={emailError ? emailErrorMessage : ""}
              />
            </Box>
            <Box mb={2}>
              <TextField
                margin="dense"
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                variant="standard"
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => passwordHandler(e)}
                error={passwordError}
                helperText={passwordError ? passwordErrorMessage : ""}
              />
            </Box>
            <Box>
              <span style={{ color: "#d32f2f", fontSize: "12px" }}>{error}</span>
            </Box>

            <Typography variant="button" color="info" to="/forgot-password" component={Link}>
              Forgot Password?
            </Typography>

            <Box mt={4} mb={1}>
              <Button variant="gradient" color="newColor" fullWidth onClick={signInHandler}>
                sign in
              </Button>
            </Box>
            <Box mt={3} mb={1} textAlign="center">
              <Typography variant="button" color="text">
                Don&apos;t have an account?{" "}
                <Typography
                  onClick={() => {
                    navigate("/sign-up", { replace: true });
                  }}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  variant="button"
                  color="info"
                  fontWeight="medium"
                  textGradient
                >
                  Sign Up
                </Typography>
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          </Box>
```

How can I solve this styling issue?

Comment: take a look at `InputAdornment` and how it's used here https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#input-adornments

Comment: The exclamation mark is not placed. It is coming by setting error property to true.

Comment: I think the point that @SandilRanasinghe is trying to make is that the icon is not displayed by default on an MUI `error={true}` Textfield by default.  That appears to have been added, possibly in your theme or via some custom implementation of the Textfield, etc. (And does not appear to be an input adornment.) In short, the code that you provided here may not help us troubleshoot the problem that you are having or we are misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @SteveGomez, yes, I am using the paid theme provided by my client. And for the solution, I have used the form helper text component. By using it I am not getting any style issues. Thanks for your help.